# Is killing infidels allowed in Hindu Scriptures?

Tags: vedas, bhagavata-purana, yajur-veda, atharva-veda

**Yajur Veda 13.12,**

> ”O king, make progress in thy duty of administration, extend happiness
>   to the virtuous. O terrible chastiser, burn down the irreligious foes.
>   O splendid person, humiliate and consume utterly like dried up
>   stubble, him, who encourages our foe.”

**Atharva Veda 12.5.62**

> Rend, rend to bits, rend through and through, scorch and consume and
>   burn to dust, the one who rejects the Vedas

**Atharva Veda 12.2.23**

> He who dwells fixed in the atmosphere, smiting the blasphemers of the
>   god that do not sacrifice to him be reverence with ten
>   Sakvari-stanzas.

**Atharva Veda 10.3.3**

> This charm shall conquer and cast down thy foemen. Be thou the first
>   to slay the men who hate thee.

**Atharva Veda 20.93.1**

> May our hymns give you great delight. Display your bounty, Thudered.
>   Drive off [kill] the enemies of the Vedas.

Everyone must kill Blaspemers:

**Rig Veda 6.72.1**

> ye killed all darkness and the Gods’ blasphemers.

**Srimad Bhagvatam 4.4.17**

> Sati continued: If one hears an irresponsible person blaspheme the
>   master and controller of religion, one should block his ears and go
>   away if unable to punish him. But if one is able to kill, then one
>   should by force cut out the blasphemer’s tongue and kill the offender,
>   and after that one should give up his own life.

Comment: Where did you get these translations? Rig Veda 9.13.9 says according to Griffith, 'O Pavamamas, driving off the godless, looking on the light, Sit in the place of sacrifice'. There is no Rig Veda 8.70.11 verse at all. Rig Veda 1.84.8 is talking of a man who does not offer gift to Indra and not about any infidel. Rig Veda 8.64.1-2 does not talk about any infidel either. Yajur Veda 13.12 is talking of burning down the King's enemies and not infidels.

Comment: What would be the point? You must have searched the internet and come up with these examples. I checked these examples with the English translation of Rig and Yajur Veda in my library and found that they are not talking about infidels. Do not believe whatever is posted in internet.

Comment: There is no concept of "infidel" or punishing them like it exists in other religions.

Comment: even if it is allowed, the verses are only praying to higher powers to kill infidels, not doing it ourselves.

Comment: Ajay, fyi, do not put space between @ & Ram or @ Pradip, otherwise I won't get notified.. the correct syntax is @ram, not @ ram

Comment: Infidel and blasphemer are not vedic terms, they are Islamic terms. Even if your translations are correct (other than the use of those words), none of the verses cited call for any human being to kill anyone. They are verses that are calling on the gods for protection. I don't see how prayers for protection leads to your question.

Comment: Ajay Do you now want the answer from all the Hinduism scriptures as well ?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Of course. I already got real translation of many verses which are claimed to call for killing infidels. But not for these.

Comment: @Ajay - Yes , there are verses In Atharva-Veda about requesting a deity to eliminate foes , a good number of. But as you can see  i have aslo mentioned in my answer that its not fully supported. And eliminating foes or getting rid of them OR people from other  regions cant be considered as killing of infidels , as there was no clear concept of religion at the time these verses were written.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I know already that many people will downvote this too.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar What? Digital Video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60987/discussion-between-swiftpushkar-and-ajay).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you making statements or asking for clarification on the translations you found?

Comment: Without the question in the body, it looks like this is not a real question and you are answering your own question in the body. If that is the case, your question will be closed as unclear. I have added questions and rolled back the edits. Why?

Comment: There is no 12.5.62 in Atharvaved.

Comment: The translation of the verse of the Atharvaveda 12.5.62 that you have given is wrong, there is nothing like "those who reject the vedas" in the original verse. The original and the correct translation of the verse is given below, > ATHARV VEDA; 12.5.62 > Rend, rend to bits, rend through and through, scorch and consume and burn to dust SOURCE: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av12005.htm

Comment: I think I read Sati's quote in Ram Charit Manas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No** , killing of Infidels are not fully allowed in Vedas. There are some mantras in Atharva-Veda which asks god  agni about destroying evil minds of foes , pardoning / Sheltering then , Welcoming those who came to ask pardon /shelter. Destroying only evil-nature or evil-mind of foes and not the people , even Atharva-Veda prays to god agni for welfare of son's and daughter's of evil-minded people and to motivate them towards good path.

**Atharva-Veda , First Kandam , Sukta 7 & 8 , YatudhanNashan Sukta.**

Atharva-Veda Samhita , Translated by Pandit ShriRam Sharma Acharya. Published by - Yuga Nirmaan Yojana , Mathura , Uttar-Pradesh , which is a hindi translation.

These are some of the mantras from Atharva-Veda.

> पश्याम ते वीर्यम्  जातवेदा प्र णो ब्रुहि यतुधानान नृचक्ष: ।
>  त्वया
>   सर्वे परितप्ता: पुरस्तात त आ यन्तु प्रब्रुवाणा उपेदम ॥ 7.5॥
>
> O Agni you are the form of the  knowledge , let us see your bright
>   bravery. You are the guide to whom who have lost the right way. By
>   your grace lead our foes to the right path. By your order, let wickedness
>   come here to repentance by identifying themselves.
>
> ---
>
> अयं स्तुवान आगमदिमं स्म प्रति हर्यत ।
>  बृहस्पते वशे लब्ध्वाग्निषोमा
>   वि विध्यतम् ॥ 8.2॥
>
> Welcoming those wicked minded people who came here for
>   repentance. O guiding star! source of bright knowladge! By your grace
>   take them in your control. To cure them, O Agni & Soma examine them.
>
> ---
>
> यातुधानस्य सोमप जहि प्रजां नयस्व च ।
>  नि स्तुवानस्य पातय
>   परमक्षुतावरम् ॥8.3॥
>
> O Soma! you let us drink the nectar of knowledge by your grace. Let the
>   evil-nature gets destroyed by roots, let this reach to the children
>   of evil-minded once & let them also be made good minded. Let the eyes be
>   lowered of those, who praise you.

---

**so from above shlokas of Atharva-Veda it is clear that vedas do not at all support/suggest the concept of infidels. It supports a Humanist approach towards enemies, evil-minded people.**

---

[image]

Comment: @ajay is correct in the sense that Vedas allow Gods (Agni, Indra) to kill infidels, but not do it ourselves

Comment: @ram - Yes ,You are correct , those mantras never are saying "let us kill" or something like that. Instead they are asking & praying to gods to do this but not doing themselves.Your point is very IMP :-)

Comment: Infidel and blasphemer are not vedic terms, they are Islamic terms. Even if his translations are correct (other than the use of those words), none of the verses cited call for any human being to kill anyone. They are verses that are calling on the gods for protection. I don't see how prayers for protection leads to the question he's asked.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda - Swamiji   I totally agree with you on this point. But we see  such or words with  similar meaning in both Indian and Western translation.Indian translation is more justifying as those translators are pandits of sanskrita and very well versed with scripture like Mr.Satavlekar etc. And above all Indian translators are not corrupt and not deliberately corrupting Hindu texts.My answer is totally depend on Translation as I have not studies enough even to pass single comment on such a deep subject like vedas.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I think "infidel" here is not appropriate term as it is not related which we can see from Hindi translation.

Comment: @TheDestroyer read the Vishnu and srimad bhagavatam verses which I provided

Answer (score 3):

https://primitivehindu.wordpress.com/2019/06/11/vedas-teach-to-kill-infidels-rubbish/

> Yajur Veda 13.12: Rise up, O Agni, spread thee out before us, burn down our foes, thou
>   who hast sharpened arrows. Him, blazing Agni! who hath worked us
>   mischief, consume thou utterly like dried-up stubble. (Griffith)

There is no reference to irreligious here. That is a mistranslation.

> Atharva Veda 12.5.62: Rend, rend to bits, rend through and through,
>   scorch and consume and burn to dust. (Griffith)

Again there is no reference to infidels or irreligious. This hymn and previous hymn is all about On the duty of giving cows to Brāhmans, and the sin and danger of withholding the gift.

Atharva Veda 11.2.23 (Not Atharva Veda 12.2.23):

> यो३न्तरिक्षे तिष्ठति विष्टभितोऽयज्वनः प्रमृणन् **देवपीयून्**। तस्मै नमो॑
>   दशभिः शक्वरीभिः
>
> Homage be paid him with ten Sakvari verses who stands established
>   in the air's mid-region, slaying non-sacrificing God-despisers! (Griffith)

This verse is basically describing Rudra who killed those who are **Devapiyun (देवपीयून्) which means god blasphemers**. Nothing about ordering believers of Vedas to kill who are god blasphemers.

Further, in the Vedas Dasyus are mentioned as Devapiyun. So, this verse says Rudra destroyed Dasyus.

> Atharva Veda 10.3.3 This charm shall conquer and cast down thy foemen.
>   Be thou the first to slay the men who hate thee.

This hymn is in the context of addressing to some other human. So, when the 3rd verse says “be you the first to slay the men who hate you”, it is addressing to some other human and advising him to use this hymn to slay the one who hate him. This is not about killing those who hate god.

In Atharva Veda 20.93.1 the word Brahmadvish is translated as those who are enemy of Vedas. Only Raksasas are mentioned in the Vedas are Brahmadvish (Rig Veda 7.104.2), which means this verse is a prayer by sages to kill Rasksasas.

> Rig Veda 6.72.1:
>
> इन्द्रासोमा महि तद वां महित्वं युवं महानि परथमानि चक्रथुः | युवं
>   सूर्यं विविदथुर्युवं सवर्विश्वा तमांस्यहतं **निद**श्च ||

The Sanskrit word “nida” here is a compressed form of Devanido (देवनिदो). In the Vedas, Raksasas are mentioned as Devanido, so this verse is also about Indra and Soma killing Raksasas.

Comment: Are you quoting from the blog post on line 1? If not, not sure what's it doing in the answer...

Comment: @sv. Yes I am quoting from that blog. Read that blog fully. All of the verses mentioned in the question are analysed there.

Answer (score 1):

This all is copied from a muslim sources.

And the vedas aren't contains the verses like Qur'an or Bible.

These all are the hymns with which we pray to god.

And If you read the names of the hymns from  Vedas, the subject of them are given in their title. And those meanings are also very clear.

Not a single verse from any vedas commands to kill any living creature.

They all are the hymns. For example
atharva veda 12:2:23
Which means, Atharva veda book-12 - hymn-2. 
 The name of hymn-2 is **A funeral hymn, and deprecation of Agni the Consumer of corpses**.

Comment: whether killing infidels is allowed or not - the track record of hinduism isn't praiseworthy against Muslim and christian invaders.

Answer (score 0):

**Context**:

यह सारी verses में एक भक्त अपने आप पर हुए हुऐ अत्याचार को भगवान को सुना रहा है, भगवान से प्रार्थना कर रहा है कि जिन्होंने हमपर अत्याचार किया है आप उन्हे सजा दीजिए, **ना की भगवान अपने भक्तो को किसी को मारने को कह रहे है।** और भक्त भी स्वयं हत्यार उठाने के बजाय भगवान से कह रहा है कि आप उन्हे सजा दो। ये तुमने जितने भी verses ko mention किया है उसमे भगवान नही कह रहे है की तुम किसी को मार डालो।
वेद भारत का इतिहास है। उस समय राक्षस आर्य समाज को परेशान करते थे, राक्षस कभी भी आर्य समाज पर हमला कर देते थे, उनकी गाय, बकरी, खेतीओ को नष्ट कर देते थे। स्त्रियों पर अत्याचार करते थे, इसी लिए वो लोग भगवान को अपना दुखदर्द सुना रहे है।

**Atharva veda 20.93.1**

**उत् त्वा मन्दन्तु स्तोमाः कृणुष्व
राधो अद्रिवः अव ब्रह्मद्विषो जहि.**.

Translation:
हे वज्रधारी इंद्र! यह स्तुति तुम्हें प्रसन्न करने वाली हो. तुम ब्रह्मद्वेषियों को नष्ट करो तथा हमें धन दो.

**Yajurveda 13.12**

**उदग्ने तिष्ठ प्रत्या तनुष्व न्यमित्राँ २ ओषतात्तिमहेते.
यो नो अराति समिधान चक्रे नीचा तं धक्ष्यतसं न शुष्कम्..**

Translation:
हे अग्नि ! ऊपर की ओर स्थित रहिए. आप अपने रूप का विस्तार कीजिए. आप हमारे अमित्रों को भस्मीभूत कर दीजिए. जो हमारे नीच शत्रु हैं, उन्हें आप सूखी समिधा की भांति जला कर राख कर दीजिए।

**Atharva veda 11.2.21**

**मा नो गोषु पुरुषेषु मा गृधो नो अजावि. अन्यत्र वि वर्तय पियारूणां प्रजां जहि..**

Translation:
हे रुद्र! हमारी गायों, पुत्र, भृत्य आदि को मारने की इच्छा मत करो . हमारी बकरियों एवं भेड़ों की हिंसा करने की बात मत सोचो. हे शक्तिशाली रुद्र! अपना आयुध हमें छोड़ कर अन्यत्र चलाओ तथा देव हिंसकों की संतान का वध करो.

**Atharva veda 1.7.7**

**त्वमग्ने यातुधानानुपबद्धाँ इहा वह. अथैषामिन्द्रो वज्रेणापि शीर्षाणि वृश्चतु..**

Translation:
हे अग्नि! तुम रस्सी आदि से राक्षसों के हाथपैर बांध कर उन्हें यहां ले आओ. इस के पश्चात इंद्र अपने वज्र से उन के सिर काट दें.

**Atharva veda 2.19.1**

**अग्ने यत् ते तपस्तेन तं प्रति तप यो ३ स्मान् द्वेष्टि यं वयं द्विष्मः.. (१)**

Translation:
हे अग्नि देव! तुम्हारी जो तपाने की शक्ति है, उस से उस को संतप्त करो जो हम से द्वेष करता है अथवा हम जिस से द्वेष करते हैं.

**Rigveda 6.44.11**

**मा जस्वने वृषभ नो ररीथा मा ते रेवतः सख्य रिषाम. पूर्वीष्ट इन्द्र निष्षिधो जनेषु जह्यसुष्वीन्प्र वृहापृणतः.. (११)**

Translation:
हे अभिलाषापूरक इंद्र! हमें हानिकारक राक्षसों को मत सौंपना. तुझ धनस्वामी की मित्रता पाकर हम दुःखी न हों. शत्रुओं तक तुम्हारी रस्सियां फैली हुई हैं. तुम सोम न निचोड़ने वालों को मारो एवं इव्य न देने वालों को समाप्त करो.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).